# "Talk to action" in French

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I setup a GoogleHome Action that works in the Preview console

- I can write "Talk to my Action"
- I get my answers

How can I test that action on GoogleHome in French ? Any workaround ?

- I tried an Alias in the mobile app to trigger "Talk to" but it doesn't work
- IFTTT works in French ! So I assume it's possible to plug it's own action

Answer (score 5):

Although Google Home and the Google Assistant is available in French, Actions is not (yet) supported. At I/O it was announced that it would be available this year, and Google has been rolling out additional language support for Actions, so hopefully this will be announced soon - but it isn't available yet.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, I found a "workaround", which let me call my french api.ai agents thru a real google assistant.

I've made an IFTTT applet (with GoggleAssistant service), which can understand a "Say a phrase with a text ingredient", like "mybot $"

So when I said "mybot fait ce que tu as a faire", IFTTT send the ingredient ("fait ce que tu as a faire") to a webservice of my own, which query my agent on api.ai, with the apiai python lib.

The agent do what it can do, and ifttt sends back a poor response (just a text).
I loose the answer of my agent, and kill its interactivity.

But it can handle actions, for now.
It's usable til assistant can invoke agent with french language